# What are invoker's rights with respect to Oracle PL/SQL functions?

Tags: oracle, plsql

The first of the result_cache usage restrictions [(--link)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#LNPLS701) is - not defined in a module that has invoker's rights or in an anonymous block.

What does "invoker's rights" mean ? Does it mean the user_procedures.AUTHID shouldnt be "DEFINER" for this function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Invoker and Definer Rights When Executing Oracle PL/SQL Code

The rule you are interpreting restricts usage of certain kinds of PL/SQL code that is stored in the database cache.  The types of PL/SQL code included are segments that are within:

1. `ANONYMOUS BLOCKS` (i.e., these are code snippets run through SQL Plus or some other input without actually being a part of a persistent object in the database, such as a stored procedure, function or package)
2. `DEFINED WITH INVOKER's RIGHTS`: (See Below for Explanation)

An `INVOKER` means that whatever `USER` account that executes a PL/SQL Object, the procedure runs with the privileges of that USER account instead of the customary privileges which are those of the `DEFINER` (owner of the object).

Tom Kyte has [a good discussion thread](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1168835334321) on the topic of definer vs. invoker rights on his Ask-Tom site.

The most notable comment from the above reference is this example block of code:

```
In the above, if user1 created:

create or replace procedure proc1
authid current_user
as
begin
   for x in ( select * from my_table ) loop 
     null;
   end loop;
end;
/
```

In the following line: `authid current_user`, this is the comment for setting an INVOKER's rights.  The table `my_table` in the reference has multiple possibilities:

- When `PROC1` is executed where the DEFINER and the INVOKER are the same, (i.e., `OWNER` or `USER1`) this table will be: `USER1.MY_TABLE`
- When `PROC1` is executed by an INVOKER or user other than the `OWNER` of the procedure `PROC1`, (i.e., `USER2`) this table can be one of these possible targets:

  - A `PUBLIC` owned table named `MY_TABLE`
  - A Private or Publicly owned `SYNONYM` for a table typed object called `MY_TABLE`
  - A local TABLE owned by `USER2` (i.e., `USER2.MY_TABLE`) of the same name, `MY_TABLE`.

*If the above cases are true, then there is a great deal of ambiguity surrounding the reference involved with the procedure* `USER1.PROC1`.  The actual, physical table being used are different based on the context of the invoking user identity and the accessibility/existence of aliased pointers (`SYNONYMS`).

The result is that the usefulness of a cached value for a procedure with INVOKER's rights enabled is questionable given the variable nature of its internal references.